# How do I measure the execution time of python unit tests with nosetests?

Tags: python, nosetests

Is there a way to time the execution time of individual Python tests which are run by nosetests ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You might try the nose plug-in posted here: https://github.com/mahmoudimus/nose-timer (or available via pip / PyPi). You can also use the built-in plugin `--with-profile` to do more serious profiling.

Comment: nosetests -s --with-xunit --with-profile `find . -name "*test.py"`
Usage: nosetests [options]

nosetests: error: no such option: --with-profile

Comment: hrm, works for me. Are you running the latest version of nosetests? (seems to be 1.0.0) See here for info about profiling: http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/1.0.0/plugins/prof.html

Comment: Try `python -c 'from hotshot import stats'`, I think that will break on you and tell you to install the python-profiler package.

Comment: The hotshot profiler that nose uses by default isn't really supported anymore, I believe. I wrote a plugin to use cProfile instead, which you can find here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-cprof/0.1-0

Comment: nose-cprof not working for me. pip install looks fine, but the flag seems to be not found: no such option: --with-cprofile. 
 --with-profile seems to work for me thoug

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively:

```
python -m cProfile -o profile.out `which nosetests` .
```

The output from can be viewed using, for example, [runsnakerun](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/), which makes it visually very obvious where your performance problems are. (e.g. it might be in a common method that many tests indirectly call)